# Integrating javax validation with JavaFX

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, javafx, bean-validation

I have worked on several Spring MVC projects where the validation could be done very simply like such :

***CONTROLLER***

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/newHeightUnit"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveHeightUnit(@Valid HeightUnit heightUnit, BindingResult result, ModelMap model) 
{
    boolean hasCustomErrors = validate(result, heightUnit);
    if ((hasCustomErrors) || (result.hasErrors()))
    {
        setPermissions(model);

        return "heightUnitDataAccess";
    }
    heightUnitService.save(heightUnit);
    session.setAttribute("successMessage", "Successfully added height unit \"" + heightUnit.getName() + "\"!");
    return "redirect:/heightUnits/list";
}

private boolean validate(BindingResult result, HeightUnit heightUnit)
{
    boolean hasCustomErrors = false;
    if (heightUnitService.nameExists(heightUnit))
    {
        FieldError error = new FieldError("heightUnit", "name", heightUnit.getName(), false, null, null, 
                heightUnit.getName() + " already exists!");
        result.addError(error);
        hasCustomErrors = true;
    }
    return hasCustomErrors;
}
```

This would validate the entity against whatever validation annotation it had (@NotNull, @Size, @Digits, etc).

How can the same be achieved in JavaFX?  I have 9 entities all with their validation annotations as I was doing in my MVC projects.  I am using Spring with what you could call a view / service / dao structure.  I do not use FXML at all, my UI components are all generated in pure Java and I intend for it to stay that way.

How can I use the validation annotations on my entities in a similarly friendly approach to that of Spring MVC?

***Clarifications***

Just for reference, this is how my entities are currently saved.  There is currently no validation of the user's inputs whatsoever when they are added but everything works perfectly fine.  My entities are all annotated and ready to go and i'm just looking to learn how to integrate the good ol' `@Valid` into the mix:

```
@Override
public void saveEntity() 
{
    TextField nameField = (TextField)formFields.get(0);

    try
    {
        Category newCategory = new Category(null, nameField.getText(), new Date(), null);
        categoryService.save(newCategory);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.error("Error adding category : " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can look at [these frameworks](https://github.com/mhrimaz/AwesomeJavaFX#frameworks) to see if any fit your needs.

Comment: I’m not clear on what result you desire.  Is it enough to get a collection of [ConstraintViolation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/ConstraintViolation.html) instances?  To display the failed validations, you would have to create and set the corresponding JavaFX elements yourself (probably Label or Text nodes).

Comment: I'd like similar functionality to adding @Valid in a controller signature.  I know it won't be that simple so i'm open to more elaborate solutions.  Having a set of exceptions resulting from validating entities would be perfect.  I've only ever used the valid annotation in controller signatures and let Spring work its magic so i'm not really sure where to even begin to explicitly validate the entities.  If you could point me in the right direction that would be great!

Comment: looks like i may have found my answer : https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i ended up with a pretty clean result.  First off i ended up with a validator class that looks something like this :

```
public class EntityValidator 
{
    ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
    Validator validator = factory.getValidator();

    public Set<ConstraintViolation<Category>> validateCategory(Category category)
    {
        return validator.validate(category);
    }
}
```

I am using Spring to make this class available for autowiring :

```
@Bean
public EntityValidator entityValidator()
{
    return new EntityValidator();
}
```

The bean validation goes something like this :

```
TextField nameField = (TextField)formFields.get(0);

    try
    {
        Category newCategory = new Category(null, nameField.getText(), new Date(), null);

        Set<ConstraintViolation<Category>> errors = validator.validateCategory(newCategory);

        if (errors.isEmpty())
        {
            categoryService.save(newCategory);

            close();
        }
        else
        {
            showErrorMessages(errors);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.error("Error adding category : " + ex.getMessage());
    }
```

The showErrorMessages method just takes the error Set and displays the first error in an error dialog.  Since i am using validation groups, there is never more than one error in the Set so this all looks pretty clean.  It will never be as simple as doing it from a controller in a web project but i'm pretty happy with the result overall.

Cheers